# Can't get latlng of current location as required

Tags: leaflet

I've setup my map so it shows my location. But I'd like to just grab the latlong (of my location) as I need it and not through onLocationFound as this can be triggered multiple times every second.

I then want to send the lat long data to a database, hence why I don't want to write the data out multiple times every second using onLocationFound.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

No: the [HTML5 Geolocation API](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) that is the core technology this feature is built around is an [asynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony) API: its results are not guaranteed to be immediately available, because they could be the result of multiple network accesses or of booting up idle hardware like your phone's GPS chip. You'll need to wait for onLocationFound.